# Tridion Monitoring Service Set up Issues in 2009

Tags: 2009, monitoring

While setting up the Monitoring service in one of the TCM server, it checks the heartbeats correctly (Tridion services). But, while trying to check different "ServiceHealthMonitor" gives the following errors:

```
    [Info  26-11-2013 09:14:42] TMA-PO-10001 Service WorkFlowListener - Health check failed. Status: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
[Info  26-11-2013 09:14:43] TMA-PO-10001 Service WebDAV - Health check failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
[Info  26-11-2013 09:14:43] TMA-PO-10001 Service IIS#local - Health check failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
[Info  26-11-2013 09:14:43] TMA-PO-10001 Service BusinessConnector - Health check failed. Status: HTTP/1.1 401
```

I have checked from IIS, the .asmx files (referred in the configuration file) are accessible. 
Could you please suggest what could be the issue? I have tried with different set of credentials, but nothing works? Also, please give idea on "SNMP" configuration and setup? Can this be used for mailing as well?

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be missing the `ServiceHealthMonitors` configuration with Authentication. You need to configure the userid/password for each health monitor for any CMS service monitoring. Please take a look at the `cd_monitor_conf.xml` (shipped with tridion binaries and located under folder: `Content Delivery\resources\configurations`) for examples

e.g.;

```
<ServiceHealthMonitorBindings>
       <ServiceHealthMonitorBinding Name="HttpServiceHealthMonitor" Class="com.tridion.monitor.polling.HTTPHealthMonitor"/>
       <ServiceHealthMonitorBinding Name="JSONPostServiceHealthMonitor" Class="com.tridion.monitor.polling.JSONPostHealthMonitor"/>
       <ServiceHealthMonitorBinding Name="XmlHttpServiceHealthMonitor" Class="com.tridion.monitor.polling.XMLHTTPHealthMonitor"/>
       <ServiceHealthMonitorBinding Name="RmiServiceHealthMonitor" Class="com.tridion.monitor.polling.RMIHealthMonitor"/>
       <ServiceHealthMonitorBinding Name="JmsServiceHealthMonitor" Class="com.tridion.monitor.polling.JMSHealthMonitor"/>
       <ServiceHealthMonitorBinding Name="WebDAVServiceHealthMonitor" Class="com.tridion.monitor.polling.WebDAVHealthMonitor"/>
    </ServiceHealthMonitorBindings>

 <ServiceHealthMonitors>
             <!-- CMS Monitoring -->
        <HttpServiceHealthMonitor ServiceType="IIS" ServiceInstance="local" PollInterval="5m" TimeoutInterval="30s">
            <Request URL="http://{cms.tridion.com}/index.html"/>
            <Authentication Scheme="Basic" Username="admin" Password="admin"/>
            <Response SuccessPattern="Welcome"/>
        </HttpServiceHealthMonitor>
              <!-- Core Service monitoring -->
        <XmlHttpServiceHealthMonitor ServiceType="ContentManagerKernel" PollInterval="10m" TimeoutInterval="30s">
            <Request URL="http://{cms.tridion.com}/webservices/CoreService2012.svc/basicHttp" SOAPAction="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2012/ICoreService/GetCurrentUser"/>
            <Authentication Scheme="NTLM" Domain="domain" Username="user" Password="password"/>
        </XmlHttpServiceHealthMonitor> 
</ServiceHealthMonitors>
```

If you want to monitor the outbound email, you need to add `HttpServiceHealthMonitor`

```
    <HttpServiceHealthMonitor ServiceType="IIS" ServiceInstance="OME" PollInterval="5m" TimeoutInterval="30s">
        <Request URL="http://{cms.tridion.com}/WebUI/Editors/OnlineMarketing/PollWebServices.aspx?mode=Monitoring" /> 
        <Authentication Scheme="NTLM" Host="host" Domain="domain" Username="username" Password="password"/>
        <Response SuccessPattern="Polling finished successfully" /> 
    </HttpServiceHealthMonitor>
```

Hope the information helps